# How to implement the canvas view inside Scrollview

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-scrollview

I'm developing the drawing type of application, I want to implement the canvas view inside the  Scrollview . but canvas view  is not working when implement inside the Scrollview . Is there any general procedure to implement this?

Comment: If the canvas does not work as the direct child of the ScrollView, have you tried wrapping it in a LinearLayout?

Comment: no, there is no such procedure: every android View use a Canvas, just follow the guide "Creating Custom Views"

Comment: @danBuonocore i have tried that it is not working .

Answer (score -1):

To do this, all you need is a custom view class that re-draws itself. I mean like this:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    // Constructors and other stuff
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // All your drawing here

        // Note: If you want an infinite thread (like SurfaceView) put
        // invalidate();
        // at the end of the function
        // Otherwise to trigger the onDraw, manually call
        // yourCustomView.invalidate();
        // every time you want to re-draw
    }
}
```

Then to use it, all you need it this code:

```
CustomView cv = new CustomView(this);
yourScrollView.addView(cv);
```

Comment: you will fall into infinite `onDraw` method calling

Comment: you only added some comments, your code is the same

Comment: And it's no longer infinite onDraw unless you want... as I said if you put `invalidate()` it's the same with a surface view but as an object that can be used (a View)

Comment: what does it have to do with "view inside Scrollview" ? what SurfaceView are you talking about?

Comment: From the OP: "I want to implement the canvas view". The "canvas view" as she calls it is (I think this is what she meant) is a way to draw on the canvas, and a way to draw on a canvas in Android is a thread which usually is a SurfaceView. In her case, she wants the "canvas view" to be treated as a View so she can add it to the ScrollView. (said here: "I want to implement the canvas view inside the Scrollview"). To draw on a canvas and treat the drawing as a View, you need a Custom View that is explained in my post. Is that enough explication?